# Why is JavaScript executed in any browser apart from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vaadin, content-security-policy

I am using Vaadin and want to execute a click on an Upload Component via JavaScript when a MenuItem of a MenuBar is clicked. That works well in any browser apart from Chrome. Someone mentioned that this is due to the content security policy of Chrome, but Firefox has this as well and the script is executed in FF.

The script looks as follows:

```js
function clickUpload(element) {
 // DOM 2 Events
 var dispatchMouseEvent = function(target, var_args) {
   var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   // If you need clientX, clientY, etc., you can call
   // initMouseEvent instead of initEvent
   e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
   target.dispatchEvent(e);
 };
 dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseover', true, true);
 dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mousedown', true, true);
 dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'click', true, true);
 dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseup', true, true);
}
```

```
menuBar.addItem("Import",
        e -> JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("clickUpload(document.getElementsByClassName('gwt-FileUpload')[0])"));
```

I tried several other possibilities (like direct click() on element etc.) and anything works well in FF and Edge but not in Chrome. If I type "clickUpload(document.getElementsByClassName('gwt-FileUpload')[0])" in the console of Chrome the script is executed as well.

Does anyone have an idea where this behaviour comes from?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Vaadin 8, and it is possible for you to do a design change, there is HTML5 file drag and drop support in Vaadin 8. For more details see FileDropTarget:

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/dnd/FileDropTarget.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to security reasons. I don't think that you can force a user to upload a file in Chrome.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? The user wants to upload a file in my case, but not by using the ugly Upload component, but via a MenuBar. So there is no chance in Chrome to implement that behaviour?